# Check Request object is empty Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

add multiple contacts at once. If a contact has details in a form.I want to check the if the output values are null I don't want to save the values. otherwise, save the values

```
 <tr >
 <td> {!!Form::text('contact[][first_name]',NULL,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
 </td>
 <td> {!!Form::text('contact[][last_name]',NULL,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
 </td>
 <td> {!!Form::text('contact[][email]',NULL,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
 </td>
 <td> {!!Form::text('contact[][contact]',NULL,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
 </td>
```

the problem I'm facing is

```
 $contacts =  $request->contacts ;
```

I want to check if any values in this request are not null save to database.if all the values in the request. don't need to save

Comment: $contacts is equal to what ?

Comment: Where is `$request->contacts` coming from? Your form only has som arrays.

Comment: updates the form

Answer (score 0):

Check them with a foreach loop:

```
$save = true;
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    if ($contact === null) {
        $save = false;
    }
}

if ($save) {
    //Save everything
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean you want to know if there is **any** value which is `null`, or if **all** values are `null` (or rather, any value *isn't* `null`).

For either case, there are several native array functions you could use.

### To know if any value in the array ***is*** `null`

I would use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

> `in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] ) : bool`
>
> Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is set.

In your case:

```
$save = in_array(null, $contacts);
```

### To know if any value in the array ***isn't*** `null`

I would use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

> `array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag = 0 ]] ) : array`
>
> Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback
>   function. If the callback function returns true, the current value
>   from array is returned into the result array. Array keys are
>   preserved.
>
> ... If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE ([see converting to boolean](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed.

So if you don't distinct between `null` or other `false`-y values, just use:

```
$flitered = array_filter($contacts);
```

Which will create an array of only the `truth`-y values in $contacts.

If you want to filter `null` strictly, you'll need to pass a filter callback. Since there's no `is_not_null` function, we'll define it:

```
$filtered = array_filter($contacts, function ($val) {
    return $val !=== null;
});
```

(As an aside, I've seen mentions of it being very slightly optimized to define anonymous callbacks as `static`, but that's irrelevant).

You can then:

```
$save = (bool) $filtered;
```

Casting an array to boolean will result in `false` if empty (no valid values in `$contacts`), `true` otherwise.